# Client side validation for Textbox inside Gridview control Using Javascript Or Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, validation, gridview

I am developing asp.net application, in that i have a page contains gridview with text boxes, 
in that i need to validate to fill atleast one text box in that gridview.

I googled many pages, but i have found only check box validation like [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Validate-GridView-with-CheckBox-at-least-one-checked-using-JavaScript-in-ASPNet.aspx),
when save button click, i need to validate to fill atleast one text box in deposit amount in that gridview..

[image]

please any answers would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

```
Use RequiredFieldValidator


        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAmount" ErrorMessage="Fill This"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Hi Jackson V Jose, the above code will functioning all text boxes , if i enter value in only one textbox means, it could not accept, it asks to fill value in all text boxes, what i need is when i fill only one text box means it will be acceptable, if i will not fill any text box means it should disaplay message "Please Enter Atleast One Text Box"..

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateTextBox() {
        //get target base & child control.
        var TargetBaseControl = document.getElementById('<%=this.Gridview1.ClientID%>');
        var TargetChildControl1 = "txtDepositAmount";

        //get all the control of the type INPUT in the base control.
        var Inputs = TargetBaseControl.getElementsByTagName("input");

        for (var n = 0; n < Inputs.length; ++n)
            if (Inputs[n].type == 'text' && Inputs[n].id.indexOf(TargetChildControl1, 0) >= 0)
                if (Inputs[n].value != "") return true;

        alert('Enter Atleast One Deposit Amount!');
        return false;
    }
</script>



<asp:ImageButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" ValidationGroup="valInsert" ImageUrl="~/images/save6.png"
                                                Width="40px" Height="40px" OnClientClick="javascript:return validateTextBox();" OnClick="btnSave_Click" ToolTip="Save" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CustomValidator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx(v=vs.71).aspx) and jQuery to check if at least one TextBox has text in it.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="At least one TextBox is required" ClientValidationFunction="validateMyTextBoxes"></asp:CustomValidator>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateMyTextBoxes(oSrc, args) {
        var isValid = false;
        $("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> input[type=text]").each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() != "") {
                isValid = true;
            }
        })
        args.IsValid = isValid;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You don't. The `CustomValidator` will trigger once a button on the page is clicked. You don't have to call it manually.

Comment: Yes it is, check your console for javascript errors. It will display the `ErrorMessage`